# Comparing two files with out sorting AWK

Tags: regex, awk

I have two files like this:

```
Animal Food
cat    fish
Dog    meet
cow    grass
```

second file:

```
Animal Food Price
cat    fish  45
Dog    meet  47
Got    grass 74
```

I just want to compare these two files based on the first and second column as like this:

```
Animal Food Price
cat    fish  45
Dog    meet  47
```

Usually, I will perform this with the `JOIN` function but in this case, sorting is not possible. I need results exactly the same order as on file 1
Then I tried with AWK as like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {$1 = $2; next} {print}' file1 file2
```

But it is producing some duplicate results and different order.

Comment: Since it's important to you that the output order is the order from file1 rather than from file2, you should have provided an example where the order was different between the 2 files so when we tested a potential solution using it we could tell if it worked or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
awk '{k = $1 FS $2} NR == FNR {map[k]=$3; next} k in map{print $0, map[k]}' f2 f1
```

```
Animal Food Price
cat    fish 45
Dog    meet 47
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually can do it with join and sorting is possible, you just have to decorate the input to join with the original line numbers so you can re-sort on those line numbers again in the output:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

encode() {
    awk '{print $1 SUBSEP $2, NR, $0}' "${@:--}" |
    sort
}

decode() {
    sort -k2,2n "${@:--}" |
    awk '{sub("^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"NF/2+1"}","")} 1'
}

join <(encode "$1") <(encode "$2") | decode
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file1 file2
Animal Food Price
cat fish 45
Dog meet 47
```

In real life I'd just go with what @anubhava has of course, unless I ran into memory issues or similar, the above is just for the sake of demo-ing an alternative.